# How to send file from C# to apache with mod_wsgi (django) and python?

Tags: c#, python, apache, mod-wsgi

How to send file from C# to apache with mod_wsgi (django) and python? It will be nice to see code example in both c# (client) and python (server).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C#, you can just use [WebClient.UploadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcfh1hw9%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).  For Django, it obviously depends what you're doing, but the documentation has [simple examples](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/file-uploads/).